# How to access files created within a docker container under subuid permissions

Tags: linux, docker

Here is what I have:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Unprivileged user (`fab`), without access to `sudo`
- [Rootless Docker installation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/)

All works smoothly. I'm able to run containers, mount volumes, etc, if I use `root` inside the container. But whenever I have an unprivileged user inside the container, I'm not able to write in the container to the files on a volume mounted from the host server (where permissions are 644 for files and 755 for directories and the ownership is `fab:fab`). I'm also not able to write to container-created files on the host server because they get mapped uid/gid ownership. Here are the examples:

Inside the container:

```
root@b5e2937beef0:/var/www/html# touch root-created-file
root@b5e2937beef0:/var/www/html# touch user-created-file
root@b5e2937beef0:/var/www/html# chown www-data:www-data user-created-file
root@b5e2937beef0:/var/www/html# ls -lia *-created*
4461041 -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Jan 22 11:01 root-created-file
4461049 -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jan 22 11:01 user-created-file
```

Outside the container:

```
fab@wp:~/html$ ls -lia *-created*
4461041 -rw-r--r-- 1 fab    fab    0 Jan 22 11:01 root-created-file
4461049 -rw-r--r-- 1 165568 165568 0 Jan 22 11:01 user-created-file
fab@wp:~/html$ echo "something" > root-created-file
fab@wp:~/html$ echo "something" > user-created-file
-bash: user-created-file: Permission denied
```

Now, the opposite.

On the host

```
fab@wp:~/html$ touch fab-created-file
fab@wp:~/html$ ls -lia fab-created-file
4461050 -rw-rw-r-- 1 fab fab 0 Jan 22 11:04 fab-created-file
```

In container:

```
root@b5e2937beef0:/var/www/html# ls -lia fab-created-file
4461050 -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 22 11:04 fab-created-file
root@b5e2937beef0:/var/www/html# su www-data -s /bin/bash -c "echo 'something' > fab-created-file"
bash: fab-created-file: Permission denied
```

What is the right way to deal with the mapped permissions under an unprivileged user? Googling didn't help, or I'm blind.

P.S.

```
fab@wp:~/.local/share/docker/volumes$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.2
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        2291f61
 Built:             Mon Dec 28 16:11:26 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.2
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       8891c58
  Built:            Mon Dec 28 16:15:23 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: After a full day of searching I have at least found the exact same issue as I have. It's a shame there is absolutely no response here.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by using this small script https://gist.github.com/denisvmedia/e5e1374218c9b26acc65642666eea26b . However, I faced another permission related problem, for which didn't find a solution: running `docker-compose up -d --build` had permissions issues with files written at `/home/user/.local/share/docker/overlay2/`. Also, for me it worked slow and unreliable in terms of network. So, I gave up the idea.

Comment: I since read more about the topic when I found the right keywords to search for: `docker rootless volume subuid`